# Importing Facebook Events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I am working on a feature which includes Facebook events, but I just read that Facebook API endpoint for getting events are deprecated. But still, I've got one question. How is possible that Evensi.com is still functional?

Also if I missed something, do you know any proper way how to import Facebook events based on location?

Regards,

Michal

Comment: If you check the documentation for the endpoint, it says right on top, _“This is a restricted edge. You cannot request access at this time.”_ - so maybe Evensi has gotten access, via whatever channels. But as a normal, 3rd-party app, right now you can not get access to page events.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a python script, [you can see here](https://github.com/DaWe35/Facebook-event-crawler).
It queries the given facebook page and it's events and puts the data into a MySQL table.

Also, there are some js libraries on Github, so I think it's not impossible.